# Is it possible to access the data on a failed amazon sagemaker processing job

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I've created a sagemaker pipeline in sagemaker studio and set it running. However it takes more than 24 hours to run and has since failed. Is it possible to find the container or the drive attached to the container that's running the processing job and access the data there?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/processing-job.html

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution - https://github.com/aws-samples/sagemaker-ssh-helper

Also, you can try running the script on a sample data in local mode (on SageMaker Notebook instances, not Studio) for faster troubleshooting.